# Toggle Code block

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

I feel I have written a very long [code block in a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772338/regex-get-elements-to-render-if-statement/37828163#37828163) which I'd like to be able to toggle - is there a possibility to toggle these longer blocks (I do not mean to run the snippet inside!).

Comment: What do you mean by *toggle* - it's not formatting/unformatting it as code, is it?

Comment: @Glorfindel, I think he means collapsible spoiler, like code snippets have option _"Hide snippet by default"_.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fully support the idea of collapsible spoilers, but I don't think it should be used in example from this question.

On [metaRuSO](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2666/178988) I shown a few better examples where spoilers are needed.

Sorry, but most part of my examples is in Russian as I'm more active there. I'll try to explain the idea.

- [Replacement results should be under spoilers](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/498787/178988) (in Russian)

  Each header *"Замена #"* is followed by 2 lines of code explaining what replacement should be used in Notepad++. After these lines a large portion of text goes - it's the result of replacement. It's useful to check if you are doing things right, but it is extra for understanding answer idea, so I'd like to move it into spoiler.
- [Snippet is used as a spoiler](//stackoverflow.com/q/34402369/4928642) (in English)

  The required code fragment is already shown in the question, but I fell it would be good to add the whole function code too. As it is JavaScript, the snippet is OK for such role, but even in that case I have to write *"(snippet is used to make collapsible spoiler, it's not for running the code)"*.
- [Command execution results should be under spoilers](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502102/178988) (in Russian)

Same idea as in the first example: Commands are parts of the solution, but their output is added just to show data format and transformations. No need to have them expanded by default.